# Filter recordset based on worksheet array

Tags: arrays, excel, ado, vba

I have an array containing values in Sheet1.Range(A1:A10).

After I open my recordset I'd like to filter the data based on values in my array. Is this possible at all?

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to restrict the original recordset using a WHERE clause - or do you need the other data too?

Comment: Yes, I've been trying this but not sure how to attach the variant to the end of the WHERE. I need to code something like "WHERE transaction IN [myarray]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too long for a comment, so here are a couple of functions I use (this assumes strings as the criteria):

```
Function GetStringInList(rngCriteria As Range) As String
   Dim rngCell           As Range
   Dim strTemp           As String
   For Each rngCell In rngCriteria.Cells
      If Len(rngCell.Value) > 0 Then strTemp = strTemp & ",'" & DoubleQuotes(rngCell.Value) & "'"
   Next rngCell
   ' now strip off leading comma
   GetStringInList = Mid$(strTemp, 2)
End Function
Function DoubleQuotes(strIn As String) As String
   DoubleQuotes = Replace(strIn, "'", "''")
End Function
```

so when building the SQL you could use something like:

```
strSQL = strSQL & " WHERE [FieldName] In " & GetStringInList(Range("A1:A10"))
```

Comment: Hi Rory, I figured it out in the end. I used a for...next to convert by array to csv then included that in my WHERE. Very useful trick indeed! Thanks

Comment: That's what that function does. :)